# Cant inject angular provider declared with useClass

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a global error handler class

```js
@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {

  // error stream others can subscribe to
  errors$ = new Subject<ClientError>();

  ...
}
```

I register it in `app.module.ts` with:

```
...
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorHandlerService},
...
```

Now I want to inject the error handler into other services so that they can subscribe to `errors$`, but I get an `Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for ErrorHandlerService!`. If I add  `providedIn: root` in ErrorHandlerService, injection works but the ErrorHandler gets instantiated twice which will lead to problems since I have suddenly two errors$ streams. How can I avoid this double instantiation?

Comment: What is exactly you are trying to do? You want to inject "ErrorHandlerService" or "ErrorHandler" and in both cases you want to inject the same? Well, you example shows how to define a class for ``ErrorHandler`` but not for. So try ``useExisting`` and inject ErrorHandlerService in root.

Comment: I want to inject 'ErrorHandlerService' into another service or component. Your suggestion solves the problem. I am using now `useExisting` instead of `useClass` and put `providedIn: 'root'` on the `ErrorHandlerService`. Now the service can be injected and there is only one instance of the service in the application. If you put your comment as an answer I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to inject `ErrorHandlerService` or `ErrorHandler` and in both cases you want to inject the same class (`ErrorHandlerService`)?

Well, your example shows how to define a class for `ErrorHandler` but not for `ErrorHandlerService`.

So try useExisting and inject `ErrorHandlerService` in root.